# How does WinTabber work?

Tags: winapi

How does [WinTabber](http://www.wintabber.com/) work?  It can take the main window of another application and display it as a WinTabber child window.  What system calls do this?

Comment: Sounds like a call to SetParent and probably some window style changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use SetParent().  And probably MoveWindow() to force the app to fit its main window in your tab.  And you'll have to do something reasonable when the process opens other toplevel windows, a WH_SHELL hook is probably needed.  And probably a bunch of hacks to whack popular programs into shape that don't like you messing with their main window.

Comment: Great, thanks! Googling 'SetParent' brought me [this AutoHotKey script](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic45515.html&start=5) which perfectly demonstrates the principle. Worked fine with Visual Studio floating windows - but Visual Studio kept stealing them back!

Comment: @Crosbie have you considered using WinTabber?

Comment: I do use WinTabber.   I'm curious to know how it works and what more might be done.  In particular, WinTabber can only capture windows with an icon in the taskbar.  It provides no way to capture floating child windows.